# Android Studio project import vs module import

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am running into problems here, I am pretty sure they both relate to my project structure. Here is my Project Structure:

In my Finder and Github

```
Workspace
 AppDir - This is the app project
 LibDir - This is my sdk project
```

In Android Studio my structure is like this:

```
(Note : LibDir is added as a dependency to AppDir and my settings.gradle has it like project(':LibDir').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../LibDir')

AppDir:
......\ .idea
......\ build
......\ mobile (module)
.........\build
..........\src
.............\main
................\java

LibDir:
.........\build
..........\src
.............\main
................\java
```

Here is the problem :

1. if someone clones the whole github repository, they get AppDir and LibDir in their Workspace (finder) but when they open Appdir as a project in Android Studio, they just see

   ```
   mobile (module)
   .....\build
   ......\src
   .........\main
   ..........\java

   LibDir:
   ......\build
   .......\src
   ..........\main
   ...........\java
   ```

I can't figure out that why they don't have the same structure as I have in my android studio?

How can you import a project and not just modules in Android studio?

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse inside the workspace you can have different projects.
In Android Studio you can have 1 project with different modules.

Then this structure is correct:

```
root
.build.gradle
.settings.gradle
.mobile (module)
..build.gradle
..\src
....\main
......\java
.LibDir:
..build.gradle
..\src
....\main
......\java
```

In `settings.gradle`you have:

```
include ':mobile' , ':LibDir'
```